# What are the regular holes in poured concrete walls called?

Tags: concrete

These holes are caused by bars that are put through the frame before the concrete is poured and then clamped, so the mold can't swell outward.

Is there a name for these holes though that is widely recognized?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are left over from concrete ties which are used to hold the formwork together ready for pouring concrete. They are usually called tie holes.

After the concrete is cured and forms need to be removed their ends protruding out are bent and snapped.

[image: snapped.]

Comment: The question is "is there a specific name for the holes"? If so, what is it?

Comment: we called them tie holes.

Comment: Plus 1 from me then! Logical name...  I was going to say they were called "holes"... but thought that would not be appreciated :)

Comment: @SolarMike, I respect your attitude.

Answer (score 1):

“Ando dots”. Named after Architect [Tadao Ando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadao_Ando) who popularized highlighting his design with the dots prominently showing.